# Back button being called twice in Onsen

Tags: android, onsen-ui

I understand the navigator pattern in Onsen deals with the hardware back button, going back up the stack rather than exiting the app. While this works well for the children of the top level page; for grandchildren it seems to be called twice when the back button is pressed, first returning to the parent page, then after a second to the top/root page. Should I be clearing the event somewhere ? The docs http://s.onsen.io/guide/overview.html#HandlingBackButton seem to imply I only need to write a handler if I want some different behaviour.

Comment: What Android version are you using? Also, what model is it? It works fine when I tried it so it might be device specific.

Comment: Android 4.2.1 on a HiSense Sero 7 (cheapish tablet). I think you're right, as using Hammer to provide left swipe support seems to work properly, so it must be something wrong with the hardware button itself.

Comment: Yeah, you could try replacing the event handler and see if it triggers twice when you press the back button.